# Как сделать изменение шрифта

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Проблема состоит в следующем: есть формат несколько клавиш «Жирный», «Курсив», «Очистить формат», при нажатии должно производится соответствующее форматирование выделенного текста в richTextBox.

Нашел код на С#:

`richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold);`

Как задать этот код на С++?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что на C++ у Вас и контрола такого - RichTextBox - в привычном виде нет. Смотрите. Когда Вы используете C#, то вы используете не только язык, но и огромный фреймворк, в котором есть функции для создания разных экранных элементов управления.Именно к ним относится та строчка, котрую вы нашли. Но если перейти на C++, вы оказываетесь один, под дождем, в чистом поле, и только ветер воет над головой - в том смысле, что все эти контролы Вам недоступны. (если только не использовась C++ CLI, в котором всё примерно так же, как на C#). Можно написать свой контрол, но это не так просто.

Comment: Я использовал С++ CLI. Есть возможность обойтись без своего контрола или нет? :(

Comment: `richTextBox1->SelectionFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle::Bold);`

Comment: Большое спасибо!